# mypy mix of stub files and in-line

Tags: python, types, mypy, linter

can one use a mix of stub files and inline type annotation in `mypy` ?

We have a large stub `.pyi` file and we thought to transfer it in parts. We took several functions and have removed them from `.pyi` and declared in code.
However, now `mypy` is complaining that module misses some attributes/methods. I assume it is looking inside of stub file and cannot find this method.

Comment: Why not change only the stub?

Comment: @hussic, because stub does not validate the body of the method and is limited in quality check